What is the 'live' kwarg of grab_data method (from a PyMoDAQ viewer) refering to?
I am working on PyMoDAQ software to enhance the pymodaq_plugins_nidaqmx and wondering about this particular kwarg.
Can someone explain to me what this "live" kwargs is refering to ? Is it a deprecated version of the "live_mode_available" attribute or something else ?
def grab_data(self, Naverage=1, **kwargs):
    update = False
    if 'live' in kwargs:
        if kwargs['live'] != self.live:
            update = True
        self.live = kwargs['live']
    if update:
        self.update_task()

I tried to run my PyMoDAQ viewer by snapshot and in live mode (green arrow of the viewer), and this live kwargs seems indeed True (update is set to True) when using live mode.
So I am wondering if it is another use of the "live_mode_available" attributes (maybe 1 of this 2 is deprecated ?) or indeed something else.

I'll post it here the talk about it from Sébastien Weber :

if you click on grab and that the attribute live_mode_available then the kwargs ['live'] will become True
and you'll be running the live mode from the plugin not from the control module (means sending the dte_signal as fast as possible)

For the context, it's the DAQ_XDViewer_ClassName of your PyMoDAQPlugin.
so i don't think it's deprecated.
for more information look at the documentation: https://pymodaq.cnrs.fr/en/5.0.x_dev/developer_folder/instrument_plugins.html#live-mode
